# Setting background image from array isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a random quote generator and I'm trying to set up the background image in a way that when a person click on "New Quote" button, the background image changes. I have created a function and added images array in it and animated the effect and tried to call it but it's not working...

Here's my code below. You can also see my full code at http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/RKeNQg

```
function getImage() {
  var backImages = ['https://s6.postimg.org/pk900j3a9/quoteimg1.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/pyac04ndt/quoteimg2.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/kbdz2nkv5/quoteimg3.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/suxd0et7l/quoteimg4.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/z9wdx2zxd/quoteimg5.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/56hv54wo1/quoteimg6.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/s98e4ay5d/quoteimg7.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/8fwablkrl/quoteimg8.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/rm9hes19d/quoteimg9.jpg', 'https://s6.postimg.org/85td5zvj5/quoteimg10.jpg'];

    var randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * backImages.length);

    var quoteImg = backImages[randomImg];

      $(".wrapper").animate({opacity: 0}, speed, function() {

       $(".wrapper").animate({opacity: 1}, speed);
       $(".wrapper").css(
    'background-image', 'url(' + quoteImg + ')');

     });

  };

  $("#new-quote").text(getQuote);

  $("#new-quote").on("click", getQuote);
  $("#new-quote").on("click", getImage);
```

How do I get the background image to work every time I click "New Quote" button?

Comment: speed is not defined

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNeQZX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to define variable `speed` somewhere at start of script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var speed = 1000;
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can't believe I overlooked it! And there's one last question. How do I get the background image to load once you go to the page? I was able to get the quote to appear once you get to the page by adding `$("#new-quote").text(getQuote);` and I wanted to do the same for the background image. However, I can't use the `.text` twice as it will cause the page to load two times.

Comment: simply put `getImage();`  just after `$("#new-quote").text(getQuote);`

Comment: Oh, I was able to get it to work by using `$("#new-quote").html(getImage);`, but yours is better!!

Comment: BTW, there is a line `var speed = 500` inside of function getQuote, but function getImage cant see it, because this variable is limited by its function.

Comment: oh thanks, I just edited it. However, I don't get it because I did call it again in different function? Thanks so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the jQuery method, and the whole code at your link http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/RKeNQg is fine

```
  $("#new-quote").onload(getImage);  //Wrong 

  $("#new-quote").on("load",getImage); //Use this
```